# How to correctly mock function in Jest tests when using Rollup.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, rollupjs

I'm writing a React library `MyLibrary` and bundling it with [Rollup.js](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/) `2.58.3`. I use [`jest`](https://jestjs.io/) for unit testing.

## Quick summary of the issue

I am unable to mock a module from my library using `jest`. This is due to the way rollup "compiles" my code.

Rollup uses its code splitting functionality to create many chunks. In one example, rollup splits `Alpha.js` into two chunks: `Alpha.js` and `Alpha-xxxxxx.js`. Some functionality from the original file is extracted to this "intermediate" chunk (`Alpha-xxxxxx.js`).

In my unit test, when mocking any method that was moved into the intermediate file `Alpha-xxxxxx.js`, `jest` seems to actually load the module from this "intermediate" module rather than the top level module.

This causes the test to fail.

e.g. `jest.mock('MyLibrary/dist/Alpha')` does not work since the modules are actually being loaded from `Alpha-xxxxxx.js` instead of `Alpha.js`

## Detailed explanation with example

I have a two modules `Alpha.js` and `Beta.js` in `MyLibrary`.

### `MyLibrary/Alpha.js`

```
export const Aaa = () => {
  ...
}
...
```

#### `MyLibrary/Beta.js`

```
import { Aaa } from './Alpha';
...
export const Bbb = () => {
  ...
}
...
```

### Compiled output generated by rollup

When bundled, rollup.js splits `Alpha.js` into 2 chunks `Alpha.js` and `Alpha-xxxxxx.js`. As a result of the code splitting, the compiled version of `Beta.js` now looks something like this:

#### `MyLibrary/dist/Beta.js`

```
import { Aaa } from './Alpha-xxxxxx';
...
export const Bbb = () => {
  ...
}
...
```

This compiled module from `MyLibrary` is imported in `MyApp` and the app seems to import it correctly and works fine.

#### `MyApp/index.js`

```
import { Bbb } from 'MyLibrary/dist/Beta'
...
```

### The problem

The `jest` test below fails since it does not correctly mock the `Aaa` export.

#### `MyApp/index.test.js`

```
import { Bbb } from 'MyLibrary/dist/Beta';

jest.mock('MyLibrary/dist/Alpha', () => ({
  Aaa: jest.fn(),
}));
```

However, if I mock the intermediate chunk generated by rollup, it works.

```
import { stuff } from 'MyLibrary/dist/Beta';

jest.mock('MyLibrary/dist/Alpha-xxxxxx', () => ({
  Aaa: jest.fn(),
}));
```

How can I properly mock `Alpha` from my library in my jest test?

Comment: You should run your tests from the source files, and not the generated files. In your test use ```import { Bbb } from 'MyLibrary/Beta';``` etc.

Comment: Because you only have two modules, there is always only a single chunk module generated, correct?

Comment: @jsejcksn, `MyLibrary` has multiple modules. I gave a simplified example above. Rollup automatically splits it the module into chunks depending on how it's used in other modules in the library.

Comment: @hjrshng we are importing the generated files in our app from the `dist` folder. Wouldn't it make sense to use the same import in the tests?

Comment: Do you know enough about the target chunk to identify it by the name portion of the file (ignoring the hash)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to mock a module whose filename base is deterministic, but includes a hash suffix which changes with each build. You haven't provided the full pattern for the filename of the output module chunk, so I'll use a hypothetical example:

Let's say the chunk module that you need to find is emitted in this pattern:

```
Alpha-b38ca4f6.js
```

meaning it's the literal `Alpha-` followed an alphanumeric hash of length 8, then the extension `.js`

You can express that with this regular expression:

```
^Alpha-[a-z0-9]{8}.js$
```

You can use a helper function to find the correct file name before passing it to Jest. The function should accept a directory and a regular expression for matching the file pattern. Here's an example:

`MyLibrary/utils.mjs`:

```js
import path from 'path';
import {promises as fs} from 'fs';

export async function findFileByPattern (dir, regex) {
  const fileNames = (await fs.readdir(dir, {withFileTypes: true}))
    .filter(entry => entry.isFile())
    .map(entry => entry.name);

  for (const fileName of fileNames) {
    if (!regex.test(fileName)) continue;
    const {name} = path.parse(fileName);
    return path.join(dir, name);
  }

  throw new Error('File not found matching the provided pattern');
}
```

`MyApp/index.test.js`:

```js
import { Bbb } from 'MyLibrary/dist/Beta';
import { findFileByPattern } from './utils';

const chunkFileName = await findFileByPattern('MyLibrary/dist', /^Alpha-[a-z0-9]{8}.js$/);

jest.mock(chunkFileName, () => ({
  Aaa: jest.fn(),
}));
```

---

If desired, you can even use the function to locate the chunk file name in a post-build step, and emit the value as a JSON artifact: then import the JSON in your test and use the file name value. This would allow you to skip the step of enumerating the `dist` directory each time the test is run.

Comment: I noticed that you previously accepted this answer and awarded it the bounty, but have since un-accepted it. Was there some additional issue you encountered?

Comment: Yep, sorry about that, I just wanted to double check before confirming. I've accepted it now. Thanks a ton for your help!

Comment: Glad you got it solved @wiseindy